# Inicializar alguns parâmetros do usuário usando angularjs e Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives, google-app-engine, angularjs-services

Estou tentando inicializar alguns parâmetros do usuário usando AngularJs e google cloud endpoints. Através de um endpoint getProfile, estou precisando pegar as informações do usuário como foto, descrição, idade para mostrar na tela.
Eu consigo fazer uma chamada deste tipo utilizando um form e um botão por exemplo, o que eu não estou conseguindo e fazer essa chamada antes da página ser carregada, assim quando for carregada já tenho as informações para mostrar da tela.

**Isso é mais ou menos o que estou tentando fazer:**
(HTML)

```
          <div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Profile image</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9" ng-controller='initController'>
                <img src="{{userPicture}}" class="user-image-profile" alt="User Image">
            </div>
          </div>
```

(AngularJS)

```
controllers.initController = function($scope, $http){

$scope.userForm = {
        "userEmail" : $.cookie('auth') 
            };

gapi.client.igardenendpoints.getProfile($scope.userForm).execute(function(resp) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {

    if (resp.error) {
        $scope.backmessage.messagetext = "GetProfile Error!"
        console.log("error");

             } else {


    if (resp.userEmail == "TEMPLATE"){

            $scope.backmessage.messagetext = "Error please try again!"


    }else{

        $scope.userPicture = 'https://filiperebollo1986.appspot.com/serve?blob-key=AMIfv94gWb8w5nMQbY0aUjnef8-HlVMKN9P6wGcZClk0iX4Fg3WPEXtPZwcVBbjsPsYZJ6O9sVCG_0SHmIKtDcPCj1sUIgUVYTqhl9Db8WKpdpPp-8sjFrRXXcLuJyYLaFfeRxRi7RaH7iwuUBh57u-cwsgIFNtOJacSxQK38M_XCJMzm1ws9O0';
        console.log('acho que funcionou');

    }

    }
       });

});



}
```

Vejam que estou chamando o  gapi.client.igardenendpoints diretamento no corpo do Controler, isto está correto? Porém não esta funcionando.